# Find a specific point on a circle by a point & angle between them

Tags: math, trigonometry

I use C# WPF and im stuck with that for couple of days.

[image]

How do I find point M?

Comment: Is `(a,b)` the centre of the circle?

Comment: yes..................

Comment: And since this question is about geometry and not programming, it is largely if not completely off-topic. math.SE is for general math questions (math.SO for advanced theory, which this topic is not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic trigonometry or application of a rotation matrix (not to forget: translate the center to the origin and after rotation back to its inital position):

```
XM=a+cos(C°)*(X1-a)-sin(C°)*(Y1-b)
YM=b+sin(C°)*(X1-a)+cos(C°)*(Y1-b)
```

The input to the trigonometric functions has to be in radians, 1°=pi/180, C°=C*1°.

---

In screen coordinates, you have to first replace all y components with their negatives to get a properly oriented cartesian coordinate system. And then back for screen coordinates. Combined, this leads to replacing Y1-b and YM-b with b-Y1 and b-YM, resulting in the formulas

```
XM=a+cos(C°)*(X1-a)-sin(C°)*(b-Y1)
YM=b-sin(C°)*(X1-a)-cos(C°)*(b-Y1)
```

which can be rearranged to

```
XM=a+cos(C°)*(X1-a)+sin(C°)*(Y1-b)
YM=b-sin(C°)*(X1-a)+cos(C°)*(Y1-b)
```

or

```
XM=a+cos(-C°)*(X1-a)-sin(-C°)*(Y1-b)
YM=b+sin(-C°)*(X1-a)+cos(-C°)*(Y1-b)
```

which is also geometrically sensible since a reflection on the x axis changes the direction of rotations.

Comment: how did u calculte it with out the raduis of the circle?

Comment: For a rotation you do not need the radius of any circle, it is implicit in (X1-a,Y1-B). Rotation preserves the radius.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Doesnt work for a circle: center (150,150),point1(150,3),radius(147),point2(?,?). point 2 needs to be 3,150 but it comes out 297,150.

Comment: Rotation by 90° of 150,3 is parallel to a rotation by 90° of (0,-1), which gives (1,0), and so (150,150)+(147,0)=(297,150) is exactly correct. However, rotation by -90° turns (0,-1) to (-1,0) and would give in the "big picture" (3,150). Remember, (1,0) points right and (0,1) points up.

Comment: I didnt follow. im sory, but can u repeat it by using only what im trying to achive? (the circle in the 3'th comment)

Comment: Rotation by a positive angle is counter-clock wise. If you have a vector pointing down, like the one from the center (150,150) towards (150,3), then a rotation by 90° against the clock will lead to a vector pointing left, with a larger x coordinate. -- However, what is probably at issue here is that the screen coordinate system with origin top left and y direction pointing down does not work like the typical cartesian coordinate system.